# ARM11 bad instruction `num resb 5' Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler

Attempting to compile the following in order to read a 5 byte char from stdin:

```
.bss
    num resb 5

.text
.global _start
_start:
        mov r0, $1
        mov r1, num
        mov r2, $5
        mov r7, #3
        swi $0
```

Via the following

```
as -o readstdin.o readstdin.s
```

But I get the assembly error:

```
readstdin.s: Assembler messages:
readstdin.s:2: Error: bad instruction `num resb 5'
readstdin.s:8: Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `mov r1,num'
```

I am running this on an ARM11 Raspberry Pi Zero.

Comment: is not the raspberry pi Zero the `ARMv6` Architecture

Answer (score 1):

gnu assembler does not use `resb`. Try `.lcomm num, 5` instead.
As for `mov r1, num` I guess you really wanted to say `ldr r1, =num`. You might want to consult the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html).